# Search for a first characters in a cell until a "-"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a find function. However I need to only use the first part of the contents of the cell, before a `"-"` (hyphen) . (i.e.    `yens2856826,28hn-72keysto`) writing this example I want to just get the `"yens2856826,28hn"`. And use that for my find function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Left` Function to cut the Part out and `InStr` to search for chars in a string.

```
MsgBox Left("yens2856826,28hn-72keysto", Instr("yens2856826,28hn-72keysto", "-") -1)
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much! That saved me such a headache!